# How to compare the items in 2 different listviews

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to compare the items in one list view with items in another list view with a button press. I want to transfer all items from one view to the other with this press. But only the items that are not all ready in the second list view.

What I've tried so far:

```
ElseIf Not ListView8.Items.Count = 0 Then
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView8.Items
        For Each item1 As ListViewItem In ListView7.Items
            If Not item.Text.Equals(item1.Text) Then
                ListView7.Items.Remove(item1)
                ListView8.Items.Add(item1)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If
```

When I execute this code it matches the first items in each list view then only one item changes then they don't match and that item is inserted even if it's all ready in the 2nd view.

Comment: Firstly, that empty `If` block is silly.  If what you're actually interested in the Boolean inverse of a condition then that's what you should be testing for: `If Not item.Text.Equals(item1.Text) Then` or `If item.Text <> item1.Text Then`.

Comment: As for the issue, no question is appropriate for SO unless you explain what happens when you execute the code you have.

Comment: As a general note, making changes to a collection while enumerating that collection using a `For Each` loop is not allowed.  Think of a different way.  One option might be to put all the items of interest into an array and then loop over that array to make the changes.  Another option might be to use a backward `For` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do for example:

```vb
Dim newItems = From a In listView1.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem)
                Where (
                    Aggregate b In listView2.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem)
                        Where b.Text.ToLower.Equals(a.Text.ToLower)
                            Into Count()
                        ) = 0
                Select a

newItems.ToList.ForEach(Sub(a)
                            listView2.Items.Add(DirectCast(a.Clone, ListViewItem))
                            listView1.Items.Remove(a)
                        End Sub)
```